# find number of orders required to purchase n products in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I've a sample dataset

```
order_num    order_date    email             product_id
    101        2023-06-01   xyz@gmail.com            1
    101        2023-06-01   xyz@gmail.com            2
    222        2023-06-02   xyz@gmail.com            1
    333        2023-06-03   xyz@gmail.com            3
    434        2023-06-05   xyz@gmail.com            3
    444        2023-06-01   abc@gmail.com            1
    444        2023-06-01   abc@gmail.com            2
    677        2023-06-02   abc@gmail.com            3
```

To purchase the product_id's **1, 2** and **3**, for user `xyz@gmail.com`, it took 3 orders (101, 222, 333) and it took 2 orders for user `abc@gmail.com`.

end table:

```
email               orders_to_cover_all_products
xyz@gmail.com                   3
abc@gmail.com                   2
```

how can this be achieved using sql?

Query I tried:

```
select email max(_row_number) from (
select *, row_number() over (partition by email, product_id order by order_num) _row_number from orders) where _row_number <=3 group by email;
```

Comment: And now you show us the code you wrote when you attempted to write this query

Comment: Which database are you using? (MySQL or PostGreSQL)?  Please just use the relevant tag

Comment: What if there were dozens of orders from a user that contained these 3 products? You could count all of them, but "*it took*" sounds like you want to find the minimum number of orders that they used to satisfy the constraints ("purchase these 3 products"), which is not a trivial problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is:

```
with your_table (order_num, order_date, email, product_id) as (

    VALUES
        (101, '2023-06-01', 'xyz@gmail.com', 1),
        (101, '2023-06-01', 'xyz@gmail.com', 2),
        (222, '2023-06-02', 'xyz@gmail.com', 1),
        (333, '2023-06-03', 'xyz@gmail.com', 3),
        (434, '2023-06-05', 'xyz@gmail.com', 3),
        (444, '2023-06-01', 'abc@gmail.com', 1),
        (444, '2023-06-01', 'abc@gmail.com', 2),
        (677, '2023-06-02', 'abc@gmail.com', 3)
),
meta as (
select
    email,
    product_id,
    min(order_date) order_date
from
    your_table
group by
    email,
    product_id
),
maxMeta as (
select
    email,
    max(order_date) last_date_All
from
    meta
group by
    email

)

select
    o.email,
    count(distinct order_num) orders_to_cover_all_products
from
    your_table o
join maxMeta m on
    m.email = o.email
    and o.order_date <= last_date_all
group by
    o.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the first order of each client, you want to count how many orders it took for all three products to be purchased at least once.

One approach uses window functions to aggregate the products and orders of each client in arrays. We can then filter on rows on the product list. Since `distinct` is not supported in window functions in Postgres, an additional step is needed to unnest the array of orders and count the distinct values:

```
select o.email, min(x.cnt_orders) cnt_orders
from (
    select o.*,
        array_agg(product_id) over(partition by email order by order_date, order_num) product_ar,
        array_agg(order_num ) over(partition by email order by order_date, order_num) order_ar
    from orders o
) o
cross join lateral (
    select count(distinct x.order_num) as cnt_orders from unnest(o.order_ar) as x(order_num)
) x
where array[1, 2, 3] <@ product_ar
group by o.email
```

| email | cnt_orders |
| --- | --- |
| abc@gmail.com | 2 |
| xyz@gmail.com | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nl_zcOFs)